# Swap image src?

Tags: jquery

I want to swap an image, form_arrow_down.jpg to form_arrow_up.jpg, when I click on an element, like this:

```
$(".c756:eq(0)").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper_datorpaket").slideToggle("fast");
    $("/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_down.jpg").attr("src","/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_up.jpg");
});
```

But I'm not sure I have done right at the line where the images swap, because it's not working!?

Adding some of the markup:

```
<div class="c756">
<span class="h2">Datorpaket</span><br />
<span class="normal">text</span><br />
<div class="c89"><img alt="" src="/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_down.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your markup as well please.

Answer (score 2):

This does not work:

```
$("/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_down.jpg")
```

Try:

```
$('img[src=/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_down.jpg]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working since your selector is incorrect (pointing to an actual image):

`$("/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_down.jpg").attr("src","/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_up.jpg");`

You should reference the image element and change the attribute (As an example, if your element has the id: wrapper_datorpaket_image ) :

`$("#wrapper_datorpaket_image").attr("src","/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_up.jpg");`

**EDIT**

This should work for you:

```
$('.c756 img').attr("src","/images/18.296a9c501318fd486d1800013126/form_arrow_up.jpg");
```

Comment: You're correct that his selector is not formatted properly - but how do you know what IS the proper format since there is no markup?

Comment: updated; only reason i would go with this instead of david's answer because his would change all the occurances of the arrow image. (from experience there is usually more than one if this type of functionality is required)

Comment: Sorry, but nothing happens! :( I don't know what could be wrong!? That line would have worked.

Comment: Nice, perhaps it's the CMS that I'm working with that creates the some problems. I have to try some more.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your code but much better way to achieve similar functionality is to use css to apply both images to your required element using different css class and then user jquery toggleClass to toggle between there two class when your click event occurs.